# Django Login with Model Extending User

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I have created an employee model that extends the User model. When i create an employee I can also find the same user in User.objects so I know it is created. When i try login with that user's credentials the credentials are not authenticated (incorrect username or password)

```
class Employee(User):
start_date = models.DateField()

@property
def leave_days_remaining(self):
    #to calculate
    calculated_days=10
    return calculated_days



def trial(request):

emp = Employee.objects.create(username='lll', password='pass', 
email="myemail@emails.com", first_name='Mokgadi,           
  last_name='Rasekgala', start_date=datetime.date.today())
found=User.objects.get(username='lll')
print found.email
print found.username
print found.password #Found exists 
return render(request, 'leave/trial.html')






{% if form.errors %}
        <p>{{ form.errors }}Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use `create_user` instead of `create`. Or you need to hash the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create users that can login, the password must be encrypted. You can reach this in two diferents ways.

First you can use `create_user` instead of `create`:

`emp = Employee.objects.create_user(...)`

Or you can set the password to hash:

`emp = Employee.objects.create(...)
 emp.set_password("password")`

Comment: Juts for interest sake, is there a better option between the two and why